# What is Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript

If you have no idea what I am talking about, check this out: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home (it's a JavaScript minifier)

---

On thier site, they state the following:

> The Closure Compiler compiles JavaScript into compact,
>   high-performance code. The compiler removes dead code and rewrites and
>   minimizes what's left so that it downloads and runs quickly. It also
>   checks syntax, variable references, and types, and warns about common
>   JavaScript pitfalls. These checks and optimizations help you write
>   apps that are less buggy and easier to maintain.

But can someone really explain in detail what this Closure Compiler does to my code?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure compiler will compile your code, and perform standard optimization techniques to your code.

The resulting code may or may not bear similarity when viewed superficially, but usually works exactly the same.

Comment: it wont work the same always because of certain optimizations it performs, which is not because CC is broken, but because the code being compiled, is not written with the CC guidelines in mind.

Comment: @pst: Indeed, sometimes it does not work the same unless you prepare your code properly when using advanced mode https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3

Comment: I agree with @pst, the name is unfortunate, but to *describe* what's being done as "compilation" is utterly wrong by any reasonable definition of the word.

Comment: @Amit Thanks. I really wish they could make that clear instead of saying that they make the code better.

Comment: @davin actually if I am not wrong, they actually do compile the code first and then generate a similar working code, using all generally known optimizations, and hence the name

Comment: Well if that's the case (I'm unfamiliar with the internals), then I take back what I said and you're right, although a better description would then be Compile => Optimise => Decompile.

Comment: @davin Well why not just optimize and tell the user what it did better, so the user can use this code in their on-work JavaScript file and then they can make it as small as it can be... that would be much better and make people learn to opitimize their code from the ground up to be a better programmer.

Comment: @user1426486, take a course in compilation/optimisation and you'll understand why that is close to impossible. Then work in the industry for 5 years and you'll understand why it's not even desirable.

Comment: @user1426486 that is because most of the times it makes the code a jumbled mess after optimizing. thus optimizations are always advised to be done at the end. Make functioning code(alright dont write absolutely garbage stuff, but yes, smthng that just works), and then start optimizing. Now save yourself the trouble of doing it every time, and use CC ;)

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels

> The ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS transformations include:
>
> - more aggressive renaming:
>   Compilation with SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS only renames parameters and variables within functions. ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS also renames global variables, function names, and properties.
> - dead code removal:
>   Compilation with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS removes code that is provably unreachable. This is especially useful in combination with large libraries. If you use only a few functions from a large library file, the compiler can remove everything except those functions from its output.
> - global inlining:
>   Compilation with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS replaces some function calls with the body of the function. This transformation is known as "inlining". The compiler only inlines functions when it determines that inlining is safe and saves space. Compilation with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS also inlines constants and some variables when the compiler determines that it can do so safely.

Comment: Then, why don't they make a program that actually just makes your JavaScript better and then you can minimze it?

Comment: The whole compilation process is to minify. The key to allowing global dead code  removal and optimizations flow naturally from the assumptions that allow global variable and property renaming.