# How to create a small Javascript extension language?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, namespaces, closures

I refactored my JS code recently and stumbled upon this pattern:

```
APP = (function() {
  var x,y,z;
  function foo() {}
  function bar() {}
  return {x:x, y:y, z:z, foo:foo: bar:bar};
})();
```

The advantage to this is that it creates non-global variables with the functions having access to everything defined in `APP`. So `APP.foo` can access `x, y, z`, and bar without typing `APP.bar()`, `APP.x`, etc. Everything can also be accessed globally with `APP.bar()`, `APP.x`, etc. You can also nest them:

```
APP = (function() {
  var x,y,z;
  function foo() {}
  function bar() {}

  var WIDGETS = (function() {
    var a,b,c;
    function hello() {}
    function world() {}
    return {a:a, b:b, c:c, hello:hello, world:world};
  })();

  return {x:x, y:y, z:z, foo:foo: bar:bar, WIDGETS:WIDGETS};
})();
```

So `WIDGETS` would have access to variables in `APP`, but not visa versa (`APP.WIDGETS.hello` can use `foo()`, but `APP.foo` has to use `WIDGETS.hello()`).

I tried creating this pattern using ERB (I'm on Rails), but it turned out messy. So I'm thinking of writing a small source-to-source compiler for this - something like CoffeeScript (with the minimal difference/extended language philosophy of SASS) that just compiles a few functions to alternative javascript.

I just want a shorthand.

For example, this would compile to my second code block above:

```
//NAMESPACE is a magical function I compile down to the long version in the second code block
APP = NAMESPACE(function() {
  var x,y,z;
  function foo() {}
  function bar() {}

  var WIDGETS = NAMESPACE(function() {
    var a,b,c;
    function hello() {}
    function world() {}
    //**notice the missing return statement that I don't need to manage and map to my variables**
  });
  //**notice the missing return statement that I don't need to manage and map to my variables**
});
```

Simple and small - just so you don't need to keep track of the variables. Would also like to separate the namespace like thus (so I can split it to multiple files):

```
APP = NAMESPACE(function() {
  var x,y,z;
  function foo() {}
  function bar() {}
  //**notice the missing return statement that I don't need to manage and map to my variables**
});
APP = NAMESPACE(function() {
  var WIDGETS = NAMESPACE(function() {
    var a,b,c;
    function hello() {}
    function world() {}
    //**notice the missing return statement that I don't need to manage and map to my variables**
  });
});
```

Any thoughts on how to do this? I'm not sure about everything, but I think if this existed, I'd like Javascript a lot more.

Comment: You might well go crazy trying to make this. Have a look at Closure Compiler - some possible overlap there.

Comment: Hmm.. can't seem to find similar functionality. Thanks for the reference though.

Comment: p.s. check out the answers on this page for more on what CC does, if interested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486022/what-is-closure-compiler

Comment: Yes, it seems to compress, remove dead code and optimize JS correct...? I'm trying to build something that creates a shorthand syntax that (from what I believe) extends beyond Javascript.

Comment: You're simply describing the module pattern with internal variables, I don't see any particular gains in the syntax you're using.

Comment: @zzzzBov Just looking for something with less syntax that allows variables in scope and splitting of files, while allowing global access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you might want to look into:

- Narcissus: https://github.com/mozilla/narcissus/
- Traceur: http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler/
- Reflect.js: https://github.com/zaach/reflect.js
- http://www.mascaraengine.com/doc/languagewalk
- https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS

There is also a proposal for a module system in EcmaScript 6 that could become available in the future: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules

Now, if the goal is just typing `foo()` instead of `APP.foo()` then I think creating a language superset of javascript is a bit of a stretch...

If you use CoffeeScript exporting the variables is less verbose:

```
APP = do ->
  [x,y,z] = []
  foo = ->
  bar = ->

  WIDGETS = do ->
    [a,b,c] = []
    hello = ->
    world = ->
    { a, b, c, hello, world }

  { x, y, z, foo, bar, WIDGETS }
```

In practice you seldom export every variable, in fact you some of them to be "private". You could also define the functions inside the object itself:

```
APP = (function() {
  var x,y,z;

  var WIDGETS = (function() {
    var a,b,c;
    return {
      hello: function hello(){},
      world: function world(){}
    }

  })();

  return {
    foo: function foo(){},
    bar: function bar(){},
    widgets: WIDGETS
  }

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. The github one was great. Yeah, it could be a bit of a stretch... thought I might as well ask. I just want cleaner code. Think this will probably be the best answer, so I'll approve. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is what is often called the "module pattern".  It is nice because you can define internal methods and variables which are "hidden" and can't be accessed.  It also does not pollute the global namespace.  You can read more about it [here](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) (I believe this was one of the first articles about the technique.) Also [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth/) and [here](http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/#oldschool).

However, since you are making everything "public" it is not as useful. You can do it like this (test code included):

```
APP = function (me) {
      me.x = 0;
      me.y = 0;
      me.z = 0;
      me.foo = function () { alert(me.x); },
      me.bar = function () {};

      WIDGETS = function (me2) {
        me2.a = 0;
        me2.b = 0;
        me2.c = 0;
        me2.hello = function () {};
        me2.world = function () {};
        return me2;
      }({});

      return me;
   }({});

APP.x = 1;
APP.foo();
```

And you get the same effect with less syntax.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZwCUh/

---

As a side note there are ways to write code without a compiler that gives you close to what you are looking for via prototypes.  A good example is the source code for jQueryUI.  I'm sure other libraries (prototype, moo tools etc.) can be used as examples too.

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the links. It was helpful. It's called the "revealing module" pattern. I want to make things public. Think I'll suffice and use the "module export" pattern instead - wish I thought of the minor difference.
My proposed solution allows separation of files - would would be nice (I'll live without that for now)

Comment: @CaseyChu - Yep -- I spaced out and gave an example that was totally wrong.  I've fixed those issues.

Comment: Nevermind. I tried "module export" pattern and it isn't the same. I am using your pattern already, I just don't like the fact that I need to type APP.WIDGETS.* all the time - feels so verbose compared to other languages - especially when nesting to 3 levels.

Comment: @user1090482 - in js can always do a `var shortcut = APP.WIDGETS;`

Comment: Hmm... the problem would be that "me" would be overridden under WIDGETS (or you can unelegantly select another variable name...)

Comment: @Hogan yeah... selecting another variable name. kinda wanted to avoid that (confusion and cleanliness). thanks for all the help btw.